# Is case sensitivity dependent on config?

Tags: php, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'm working on a php framework, and I just realized, that case sensitivity will be a big problem. For example: the http headers are case insensitive, but the queryString keys are case sensitive in $_GET.

Is that behavior config / http server etc.. dependent, are the queryString keys always case sensitive?

Btw. are the SQL table names and columns key sensitive or insensitive?

(I want to reach every property in camelCase... :-) )

Comment: Hmm I think it's a strange / confusing behavior, that PHP converts dashed style HTTP HEADERS to underscored style in the $_SERVER ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET params keys should always be supplied lowercase.

SQL table names are case sensitive if the platform's file system is case sensitive.

[Info on MySQL's case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: Why do you say that GET parameter keys should always be lowercase?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Because it's less confusing IMO than mixed case GET params. It may be a personal style thing.

Comment: Most of the developers using underscored or dashed style naming in GET, but I'm wondering why? You could use camelCase too...

Hmm which platform's file system is case insensitive?

Comment: > Hmm which platform's file system is case insensitive? hehe - one that should never be used as a web server IMO (Windows, if that was a serious question ;) )

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a big mess in HTTP Message case sensitivity.

Http header names are case insensitive, but http header values are sometimes case sensitive (for example: http Date) and sometimes case insensitive (for example: mime types).

Uri parts are mixed too:
case insensitive: scheme, host
case sensitive: path, queryString, fragment

So the $_GET keys are always case sensitive.

@alex: I'll accept your answer because the knowledge: "SQL case sensitivity is platform dependent" is really useful. So we have to handle SQL tables always as if their names were case insensitive. Please edit your answer and remove the "GET params keys should always be supplied lowercase." part.